# insert id returns always -1 and data is not inserted in database. please somebody help me

Tags: android, sqlite

when i insert the data then insert id always returns -1 this is my data base table.my database is created successfully. So, please tell me what i do to solve this problem.

```
query3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + StaticData.SUBJECT_TABLE_NAME + "` ("
                + "`subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,"
                + "`subject_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,"
                + " PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`)"
                + ");";

public long insertSubject(TeacherModel queryValues) {
            long insertId = -1;
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("id", queryValues.getSubject_id());
            values.put("name", queryValues.getSubject());

            if(database != null) {

                 insertId = database.insert(StaticData.SUBJECT_TABLE_NAME, null,
                        values);
            }
            Log.w(DataInteract.class.getName(),
                    "Subject::" + values + "insertID=" + insertId);

            return insertId;
        }
```

Comment: just change the value of insertId =1 or change your create query. just write Primary key Autoincrement to id. Hope it works

Comment: This code with the schema you have should be throwing an exception - your table doesn't have the columns you're trying to insert to.

Comment: Let me guess: the `if` is needed to prevent a null pointer exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code, check the below corrections

As far as I see, the insertID should always equals the subject_id you try to insert, if this assumption is not correct, you need to add a different column in your table.

Things you did wrong: Table creation is wrong, you use `MySQL` code and not `SQLite`, it might work in some cases but it is not adviced.
You had the wrong column names in your `values` (`ContentValues()`), if your database does not exist, you will still get -1.

```
query3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + StaticData.SUBJECT_TABLE_NAME + "` ("
                + "`subject_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "`subject_name` TEXT"
                + ");";

public long insertSubject(TeacherModel queryValues) {
    long insertId = -1;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("subject_id", queryValues.getSubject_id());
    values.put("subject_name", queryValues.getSubject());
    if(database != null) {
        insertId = database.insert(StaticData.SUBJECT_TABLE_NAME, null,
                        values);
    }
    Log.w(DataInteract.class.getName(),
          "Subject::" + values + "insertID=" + insertId);

    return insertId;
}
```